# Can the Knight give infinite Leadership dice for 1 minute?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, npc

I got a Knight servant from a **Deck of Many Things**, and am looking at his *Leadership* ability.

> For 1 minute, the knight can utter a special command or warning whenever a nonhostile creature that it can see within 30 ft. of it makes an attack roll or a saving throw. The creature can add a d4 to its roll provided it can hear and understand the knight. **A creature can benefit from only one Leadership die at a time.** This effect ends if the knight is incapacitated.

The highlighted sentence seems to me that it focuses on having multiple Knights, and their Leadership not stacking. If you make 2 attacks, you can have 1 dice on the first attack, and another on the second, and you don't have 2 dice at a time.

I'm playing a Bard, with my very limited Inspiration dice, and feel his ability is really strong. Since there is no apparent cost, can the Knight essentially give an extra 1d4 to **all** attack rolls and saving throws of my party (including himself) for 1 minute?

I know 1d4 isn't much, but multiplied by 10 rolls per round (a few extra attacks and a couple of saves by 5 party members) for 10 rounds really adds up!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, that's how it works. Note that this ability is balanced around being a monster feature, not a player feature. It's meant to be an interesting feature to deal with on the opposition and isn't meant to be used all the time by your own party.

Also note that if you picked the "Knight" card from the [Deck of Many Things](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things), what you get is **not** a [Knight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/knight) NPC, but a 4th level Fighter:

> ***Knight.*** You gain the service of a 4th-level fighter who appears in a space you choose within 30 feet of you. The fighter is of the same race as you and serves you loyally until death, believing the fates have drawn him or her to you. You control this character.

It might be that your DM assigned you the wrong stats for the servant, but if you do get to keep him, then indeed they have this *very* powerful ability. Best keep this guy alive as long as you can...

Comment: Oh, dear god. My poor [Toddy](https://youtu.be/9uO1A1IpAx0?t=16)

Comment: The +1d4 to attacks and saves ability is not really any more powerful than a Bless spell as far as I can see (in fact it looks almost based on a simplified version of that spell), although would have the nice feature of stacking with Bless.